# Cosa significa "s'era sdilinquita" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Non so niente di te* di Paola Mastrocola, pubblicato da Einaudi, ho letto (il corsivo è mio):

> Ma perché era stata cosí indiretta e oscura? Anche un briciolo vigliacca. Non poteva parlar piú chiaro? Invece di sperare che Fil cogliesse il senso risposto, il lato metaforico del suo circospetto alludere... non poteva parlare apertamente, santo cielo? No, aveva preferito andar di sbieco, *s'era sdilinquita a dire* quanto secondo lei era bello essere dimenticati in un autogrill, e veder ripartire il pullman con tutti gli altri sopra, e rimanere lí da soli, a terra, liberi e sganciati...

Non capisco cosa significa "s'era sdilinquita a dire" nel brano precedente. Me lo potreste spiegare? Ho cercato il termine "sdilinquire" in alcuni dizionari, ma quello che ho trovato non sembra avere senso qui.

Comment: Secondo me è un vero e proprio granchio dell'autrice, che si è lasciata trascinare da un'assonanza. Un po' come quando si usa *corrusco* nel senso di *corrucciato*.

Comment: L'avevo già detto che 'sta Mastrocola continua a inventare parole.

Comment: Credo che l'inganno abbia a che fare con *dilungata* o *sdilungata* (che già non mi piacerebbe). Il significato di *sdilinquirsi* è del tutto diverso.

Answer (score 2):

Credo, ma non sono sicura di ciò, che il significato dell'espressione sia quello di *profondersi fino ad estenuarsi*, parlando cioè con tanta enfasi da diventare esausta.

Comment: Dal contesto pare che il senso sia questo, e volendo è difendibile in base all'etimo (il latino *delinquĕre*, “mancare, venire meno”), anche se l'uso attuale è più nel senso “intenerirsi, essere svenevoli”.